# How to get Accurate Current location in android?

Tags: java, android, gps, latitude-longitude

I have tried `getLastKnownLocation()` but i found it is failed to provide accurate location sometimes and it's fetching the wrong locations, otherwise it's good.

Can anyone help me?
I am a beginner on android studio

This is my GPS Tracker Code below....

```
if (isGPSEnabled)
{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

    if (locationManager != null)
    {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        updateGPSCoordinates();
    }
}
} else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

Log.d("Network", "Network");

if (locationManager != null)
{
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    updateGPSCoordinates();
}
}

// ...

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{ 
this.location = location;
updateGPSCoordinates();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong location"? GPS is not 100% accurate and has some error. It also matters if the GPS is inddor or outdoor.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of testing these weeks and I notice that the accuracy depends very much on the phone's brand. Some has better built it GPS chips than others... Also, there is some issue with the Lollipop OS as stated here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81140

Comment: wrong location means sometimes its shows previously fetched location not the updated one. you have any idea to get updated location (not the LastKnownLocation).

Comment: @TDG wrong location means it it showing different state address , i'm using some apps they are accurate to the city atleast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a really useful page on the Android Developper [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), I hope this will help you. For my purpose, I had to tweak it a little bit but the main idea stays the same:

> You might expect that the most recent location fix is the most
>   accurate. However, because the accuracy of a location fix varies, the
>   most recent fix is not always the best. You should include logic for
>   choosing location fixes based on several criteria. The criteria also
>   varies depending on the use-cases of the application and field
>   testing.

```
private static final long TWO_MINUTES = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos(2);

/** Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
  * @param location  The new Location that you want to evaluate
  * @param currentBestLocation  The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
  */
protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getElapsedRealtimeNanos() - currentBestLocation.getElapsedRealtimeNanos();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
    // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
      return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't just cast float to int. If it really makes sense to use int I would round. Your "isSignificantlyLessAccurate" handling doesn't make any sense to me. I don't know why I should care about the provider. Google already does and sets the accuracy parameter accordingly. Accuracy and timestamp are the values I care about. A new location is NOT always better than no location. If it is too old or too inaccurate it is unusable and I prefer to use no location.

Comment: I don't use getElapsedRealtimeNanos() because I don't care about "real-time since system boot" of the device. I use UTC timestamp.